# Compare 2 files line by line without list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this project, I want to compare two lines from separate files, character by character in Python. I can't get the program to return or print anything.  The program needs to do the following:

- Read the next line from each file

`for line1 in currentLine1:
            for line2 in currentLine2:`

- Determine if the lines are different lengths

  ```
              if len.line1 != len.line2:  # If the line lengths are not equal return the line number
              return charByChar(count=count + 1, differenceCounter=differenceCounter, textCount1=textCount1,
                                textCount2=textCount2, difLineCounter=difLineCounter)
  ```
- If the lines are the same length compare characters

  ```
              if len.line1 == len.line2:  # If the lines lengths are equal
                  for char in range(len(line1)):  # Compare line by line
  ```
- If they match don't do anything. However, if they do match print unmatched characters(1); print line number using N: M format(2); Process next line(3).

  ```
                      if line1[char] != line[char]:  # If the lines have different characters
                          print("Unmatched characters")
                          print("Line number:", count)
                          print("First different character", char)
                          differenceCounter = difLineCounter + 1  # add 1 to the difference counter
                          textCount1 = textCount1 + 1
                          textCount2 = textCount2 + 1
                  return charByChar(count=count, differenceCounter=differenceCounter, textCount1=textCount1,
                                textCount2=textCount2)  # return difference count
  ```
- At the end print out the number of characters in the first file(1);the number of characters in the second file(2);the number of characters that do not match in lines of the same length(3);the number of lines that are not the same length(4).

  ```
              if len.line1 == 0 or len.line2 == 0:
              print("Extra lines are not matching")
          **Some print then return statement**
  ```

**I believe I have all this down, however, my code never returns any values. It always ends with exit code 0 (I have referenced 2 text files to compare).**

For context here is all the code I have written

```
text1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
text2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
content1 = text1.read()
content2 = text2.read()


def charByChar(count=0, differenceCounter=0, textCount1=0, textCount2=0, difLineCounter=0):
    currentLine1 = content1
    currentLine2 = content2
    line = text1.readline(count)
    if line != '':
        for line1 in currentLine1:
            for line2 in currentLine2:
                if len.line1 != len.line2:  # If the line lengths are not equal return the line number
                    return charByChar(count=count + 1, differenceCounter=differenceCounter, textCount1=textCount1,
                                      textCount2=textCount2, difLineCounter=difLineCounter)
                if len.line1 == len.line2:  # If the lines lengths are equal
                    for char in range(len(line1)):  # Compare line by line
                        if line1[char] != line[char]:  # If the lines have different characters
                            print("Unmatched characters")
                            print("Line number:", count)
                            print("First different character", char)
                            differenceCounter = difLineCounter + 1  # add 1 to the difference counter
                            textCount1 = textCount1 + 1
                            textCount2 = textCount2 + 1
                    return charByChar(count=count, differenceCounter=differenceCounter, textCount1=textCount1,
                                      textCount2=textCount2)  # return difference count
                if len.line1 == 0 or len.line2 == 0:
                    print("Extra lines are not matching")
    text2.close()
    text1.close()


def main():
    charByChar()


main()
```

Comment: Maybe it is a typo or I am missing something, but in your when you check for line length equality, you are calling `CharByChar` if they have a different length. Is this intended?

Comment: There is no base case in your recursion.

Comment: are you building this function for another project or this is more like a practice project? because I believe https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html does what you want to do already

Comment: @JChao I'm limited in what methods I can use

Answer (score 0):

Your function `charByChar()` doesn't seem to return a base case. For example, in the place where you log that extra lines are not matching, try returning `False` or `-1`, or what have you.